# Issue in JBOSS BPM Process Execution

Tags: pam, jboss, bpm

I have setup the JBOSS PAM Server and try to run some sample project, but I keep getting the following error:

> Org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundException : org/relaxng/datatype/DatatypeException

Kindly help me to resolve this.